# how to call unload event of iframe

Tags: jquery, asp.net, session, iframe

I used jquery to show multiple child.aspx pages in different tabs in my parent.aspx page.

```
$('#tabcontent').append(
'<iframe width="100%" frameborder="0" 
scrolling="no" 
onload="adjustMyFrameHeight(' + count + ');"
id="c' + count + '" src="' + srcpage + '" >' + '</iframe>)
```

Now I want to call the Page_Unload method of all the child.aspx pages on parent Unload.

What I need is to store the information on each child.aspx page in the session and then reassign the session to each page.

Comment: $('#tabcontent').append(<iframe width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="adjustMyFrameHeight(' + count + ');" id="c' + count + '" src="' + srcpage + '" >' + '</iframe>)

Comment: `Page_Unload` is called after the page is rendered. "Session assignment" is done when the request comes in from the client. I think your jargon is a bit confusing. Can you be more specific, what do you want to happen and when?

Comment: My parent page contains multiple tabs created using jquery and each tab has same aspx page with different data. When i render to another page then postback is done for parent page only(Page_Unload of only parent page is called). So, i want to get the data in tabContent for all tabs if data has been changed by user and save the changed data in session for reusing changed data as autofill(persist data on navigation) when user navigates to the parent page in same session

Comment: I think I understand. `EnablePageMethods` in `ScriptManager` will allow you to invoke server side code. [More details here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=109). Additionally you can make use of `UpdatePanels` and async triggers that you can trigger from the parent page, and this will save the state of your "tabs".

Answer (score 1):

try using innerHTML.They also only clear `document.body` (anything in the `<head>` is still present). Here is a solution that uses the DOM:

```
var frame = document.getElementById("myFrame"),
frameDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
frameDoc.removeChild(frameDoc.documentElement);
```

This solution uses `innerHTML`:

```
var frame = document.getElementById("myFrame"),
frameDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
frameDoc.documentElement.innerHTML = "";
```

replace `myFrame` by id of that frame.

Comment: Thanks for reply Milind....But my problem is about accessing data in my tabs and saving it in session and then again reload the session data on navigation to same page..i.e i have three tabs(three child.aspx pages with different data in textboxes) in parent.aspx then three iframes are created with different id's that contains textboxes with same id's(that are on child.aspx page).I need to get the data on each child.aspx page to be stored in session.